# using output from two drop down lists to create text in multiple places

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have several drop down lists as follows:

```
<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
      <option value="1000">1000</option>
      <option value="2000">2000</option>
      <option value="3000">3000</option>
      <option value="4000">4000</option>

</select>

<select name="dropdown2" id="dropdown2">
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="24">24</option>
      <option value="36">36</option>
      <option value="48">48</option>

</select>
```

I am trying to use the output from dropdowns to create text elsewhere on the page. So for example if a user selects 1000 and 24 - I can display certain output. if they select 1000 and 36, the content will be different. 16 different lots of output will be the result (based on above drop down options).

I can't work out the most simple way to achieve this without using a database. Ideally I want to use just inline code.

Thanks,

Arron

Comment: where are the contents saved if not in the database?

Comment: I figured I could just javascript and document.write the content, if I can get the two drop downs to work together? There is only 16 options, so I don't want to go down the database route.

Comment: object literal where the key maps to the dropdown value and the value is the text. Call a function once both have been selected which accesses the object maps and concatenates the text together

Comment: I understand that, but I don't want the output text to simply show the drop down selections. I want to use the two dropdown selections to call a result.

Comment: I don't think you're being very clear. If you're not using a database to retrieve the results then you can only use JavaScript. My suggestion is to use a JavaScript object to store the text in. But to reference the correct text based on the dropdown value, there must be a link. They 'key' of the object map will be the value of the dropdown box.

Comment: Sorry. Yes I think what you have said there is what I am looking for, I just don't know how to execute that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a jquery solution:

```js
$(function() {
    var firstValue = $('#dropdown').val();
    var secondValue = $('#dropdown2').val();
    
    $('#labelOne').text(firstValue);
    $('#labelTwo').text(secondValue);
    $('#total').text(firstValue * secondValue);
   
    $('#dropdown').on('change', function(){
        firstValue = $('#dropdown').val();
     $('#labelOne').text(firstValue);
        $('#total').text(firstValue * secondValue);
    });
  
    $('#dropdown2').on('change', function(){
        secondValue = $('#dropdown2').val();
     $('#labelTwo').text(secondValue);
        $('#total').text(firstValue * secondValue);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
      <option value="1000">1000</option>
      <option value="2000">2000</option>
      <option value="3000">3000</option>
      <option value="4000">4000</option>
</select>
<select name="dropdown2" id="dropdown2">
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="24">24</option>
      <option value="36">36</option>
      <option value="48">48</option>
</select>
<span id="labelOne"></span> *
<span id="labelTwo"></span> =
<span id="total"></span>
```

Comment: I don't want to multiply the numerical drop down options chosen? I want to use the option value from both drop down lists, to pick a string of text out of the 16 different possible options?

Comment: var firstValue = $('#dropdown').val(); creates a variable that you can use as text. Use firstValue as a string and look for a match in your list of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the two values as a string together. And put the 16 cases in a **switch** statement:

```
function getSpecificText(v1, v2) {
    var con = v1.toString() + v2.toString();
    var res = "";
    switch (con) {
        case "100012":
            res = "text1";
            break;
        case "100024":
            res = "text2";
            break;
        case "100036":
            res = "text3";
            break;
        case "100048":
            res = "text4";
            break;
        // ...
    }
    return res
}
```

Get the two selected values and put it in the function above:

```
function getSelected() {
    var v1 = dd1.options[dd1.selectedIndex].value;
    var v2 = dd2.options[dd2.selectedIndex].value;
    output.innerHTML = getSpecificText(v1, v2);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tu70cuc6/5/)