# Two Drop Down Lists - Pick Values - Load Page

Tags: jquery, list, select, load, html

I'm looking to make something rather simple (PHP is OK but JS is ideal): It would load the post/page by taking the user to it, or load the content of the post/page on the post/page itself (AJAX or whatever).

Ideally, it will work like this:

- A user selects a value from the first drop-down list ('Apples').
- A user selects a second value from the second drop-down list ('Pastry').
- Both lists of values in both drop-down lists are the same ({"ingredients": "Apples,Bananas,Chocolate,Cream,Dough,Gelatin,Lemon,Pastry,Peaches,Sugar,Walnut",}).
- Each combination of two values results in something different.
- The something different is a page, or text loaded on the page, for each combination of values.
- A user clicks "Submit" or "Go" or "See Combination" and it launches the website link (page) corresponding to that combination (e.g., 'Apples' + 'Pastry' loads the 'Apples + Pastry' page).

Put simply: two drop down lists, pick one value from each, click submit to load the page corresponding to the two values selected.

Edit: How would I modify this to do what I need? [using output from two drop down lists to create text in multiple places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505637/using-output-from-two-drop-down-lists-to-create-text-in-multiple-places)

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
var firstValue = $('#dropdown').val();
var secondValue = $('#dropdown2').val();

$('#labelOne').text(firstValue);
$('#labelTwo').text(secondValue);
$('#total').text(firstValue * secondValue);

$('#dropdown').on('change', function(){
    firstValue = $('#dropdown').val();
    $('#labelOne').text(firstValue);
    $('#total').text(firstValue * secondValue);
});

$('#dropdown2').on('change', function(){
    secondValue = $('#dropdown2').val();
    $('#labelTwo').text(secondValue);
    $('#total').text(firstValue * secondValue);
});
});
```

-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
      <option value="Apples">Apples</option>
      <option value="Bananas">Bananas</option>
      <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
      <option value="Pastry">Pastry</option>
</select>
<select name="dropdown2" id="dropdown2">
      <option value="Apples">Apples</option>
      <option value="Bananas">Bananas</option>
      <option value="Chocolate">Chocolate</option>
      <option value="Pastry">Pastry</option>
</select>
<span id="labelOne"></span> *
<span id="labelTwo"></span> =
<span id="total"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your html code into a `form` then in your Jquery construct the url based on the values generated from the two dropdown lists and assign it to the action attribute of the form as following:

Check [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jov0rpjm/4/) for demonstration

```
$(function () {
    var firstValue = $('#dropdown').val();
    var secondValue = $('#dropdown2').val();
    var url = null;

    $('#labelOne').text(firstValue);
    $('#labelTwo').text(secondValue);
    $('#total').text(firstValue + secondValue);

    $('#dropdown').on('change', function () {
        firstValue = $('#dropdown').val();
        $('#labelOne').text(firstValue);
        $('#total').text("http://" + firstValue + secondValue + ".com");
        url = "http://" + firstValue + secondValue + ".com";
        $('#form1').attr("action", url);
    });

    $('#dropdown2').on('change', function () {
        secondValue = $('#dropdown2').val();
        $('#labelTwo').text(secondValue);
        $('#total').text("http://" + firstValue + secondValue + ".com");
        url = "http://" + firstValue + secondValue + ".com"
       $('#form1').attr("action", url);
    });

});
```

### **[Updates]**

To Answer the question of how to get Query to load the combination as a text and display it underneath the button you can use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method. Check updated [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jov0rpjm/7/) for demonstration

Comment: Awesome! Thank You!

Comment: How would I get it to load on the page?

Comment: Could you clarify please? To load the drop-down values?

Comment: A further question: After solving the issue with the pages stated above: How would I get the jQuery to load unique text (a name or a paragraph/recipe, instead of launching a URL), displaying it underneath the button from each combination (preferably without reloading the page)?

Comment: For this all you need to use is Jquery .html() to load the combination.  I updated the answer to show you how you could achieve that. Also you could also check the link as I updated the code in fiddle to reflect the answer.